# How to mantain file structure for dynamic loading python files using Py2Exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am using py2exe in order to generate a .exe file from a project of mine.
This project contain in the root folder a main.py
In order folders, like the folder *project*, there are other .py files that should be imported only when relevant during the main.py execution.

Right now, the py2exe is packing all the files together when creating the .exe
Thus, folders like this *projects* - that are actually intended to have .py files in the final distribution - cease to exist.

Is there a way for it to keep the file hierarchy without also adding those files into the final .exe?
(i.e. not compact those folders into the .exe file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using pyinstaller instead of py2exe